# About Events to Textbox and Div

Tags: javascript

I have assigned a onClick event to textbox. When I am clicking on textbox, I want to execute the click event of div also. How to do that in Javascript?. The div and textbox are not nested they are on different position in document.

Thanks in advance for the Help.

Comment: Hi Pranjali. I'm going to answer below, but it'll be a bit of a guess. If you want more effective help, please post at least a workable (or readable) example of the situation you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a function that is called by both.

Comment: It is ok. But I want to execute div click event when I will click on textbox

Comment: That's my point; using a function that has the code that's the same between both, and make both OnClick events reference it. Differences in code can be appended to the individual OnClicks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know [even bubbling](http://catcode.com/domcontent/events/capture.html) in order to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading PPK's blog post about events. It's a bit old, but it weathers the test of time well. See:

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Answer (score 0):

If the elements are nested the event will [bubble](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) up (if you aren't cancelling it) so:

```
<div onclick="foo()">
    <input type="text" onclick="bar()" />
  </div>
```

Will result in a call to `bar` then `foo`. This is a bit of a kludge though since you don't really want to have inline event binding if you can help it. This is one of those cases where use jquery might be appropriate since `$('#mydiv, #myinput').click(baz)` is quite clean.

Comment: The textbox and div are not nested. They are in different places.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 function twoActions(){
  var textboxId = document.getElementById("textboxId");

  var divId = document.getElementById("divId");

   textboxId.style.border = "red"; // action one  

   divId.style.border = "red";  // action two

}
```

you tie this function to the textbox - onClick it will change the border color of the text box and that of the Div.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not nesting the divs, you'll need to explicitly call the .click() of the div separately.

```
function textEvent() {
    // Do all the stuff you want to do for the textbox

    // Fire the event for the div too
    div = document.getElementById('#secondDiv');
    div.click();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I am reading it as if you have 2 different functions.  We'll just say textbox(); and div();

your onclick for the textbox should read

```
onclick="textbox(); div();"
```

That should call both functions on the same event, where with the div you can put only the div() function or both like the example above.  Just seperate the function calls with a semi-colon.

Comment: "The div and textbox are not nested, they are on different position in document."